# Gulp build task fails

Tags: spfx, spfx-tooling

I'm trying to build (gulp bundle --ship) the GDPR Starter kit from: https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-gdpr-activity-hub.

It fails with the below error:

```
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'readCommentedJsonFile' of undefined
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'readCommentedJsonFile' of undefined
> [12:23:47] Error - Unknown  undefined [12:23:48] ==================[
> Finished ]================== [12:23:48] Project gdpr-starter-kit
> version: 0.0.1 [12:23:48] Build tools version: 2.10.0 [12:23:48] Node
> version: v6.11.2 [12:23:48] Total duration: 2.37 s [12:23:48] Task
> errors: 2
```

I'm using tsc 2.2.2 and npm 4.6.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under advice from a colleague I downloaded the zip of the project instead of cloning it and it worked fine.

What the difference is between cloning the project and downloading it I can't say without running a diff.